# Double clicking in phpMyAdmin gives an unwanted new browser tab (Opera/Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, phpmyadmin, opera

Double clicking in phpMyAdmin within Opera or Chrome gives me an unwanted new browser tab. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have the "New Tab Start Page" extension installed. Configure that extension and disable the option "Detect when Double Clicking on Non-Activated URL's".

Voilà.